# when to use client side web framework [angularjs/bootstrap/backbone] server side framework [JSF/Struts/SpringMVC] for Java JEE project

Tags: jsf, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, model-view-controller, mvvm

I need to choose a front end MVC/MVVM layer for a java/Jee project .

1. I am wondering how session management/database transaction management will affect if i choose MVVM based  clientside framework lets say angularjs I know this is not an issue with server side framework like JSF .
2. Is both combination below is ok . With  both can we achieve stateful/stateless nature.
   lets say a shopping cart project which is stateful .

a) MVVM (angularjs/backbone/bootstrap) + RESTful webservice (EJB3)
b) MVC (JSF/spring/struts) +   RESTful webservice (EJB3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced the same situation in a project, having to choose which presentation framework to use, the choices that I considered are : Struts2, Tapestry, GRails and Backbone.

The framework that I chose is Backbone with CXF at the server side (JAX-RS) for the following reasons : User experience and performance.

1- regarding session management : I have implemented a small module (client side) and at the server side it's already supported by the JEE platform.

2- for database transaction management, I don't think that the presentation layer (backbone ... or JSF...) affect this point, because it's managed at the business layer.

3- for stateless nature both choices are equals.

4- but for stateful nature, the application container will do it for you if you choose (JSF...) whereas with (backbone...) you will need a little more efforts to do it.